# Rails / MYSQL QUERY returns value even with no record?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails

I have a bit of code to check if a record exists in the database, but my problem is that the variable keeps returning a result even with no records ..

```
@page_of_book = Page.where({:number => @page, :parent_id => @book_id.id}).limit(1)

if !@page_of_book 
# if no page, create a new page

end
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `.empty?`, as where would always return an array. An empty array if no records exist.

```
if @page_of_book.empty?
# if no page, create a new page

end
```

Answer (score 1):

The query returns an `Array`. Even if you use `limit` you will still get an Array with 1 or 0 elements. So your test needs to be:

```
if @page_of_book.empty?
  ...
```

Comment: you are right, thanks! It worked, where would I find reference for something like this on the web ?

Comment: @jakob - The quickest and easiest way is to use the Rails console. I always run queries like this in the console first, and look at what is being returned. That way you would have seen it's an Array very quickly.

Answer (score 0):

shouldn't

```
 @page_of_book = Page.where({:number => @page, :parent_id => @book_id.id}).limit(1)
```

be

```
 @page_of_book = Page.where({:number => @page, :parent_id => @book.book_id}).limit(1)
```

or something like this?

Comment: Thanks.. the id is suppose to be there, since I want to call the .id of that record

Comment: ok just the name is very confusing, because @book_id indicates it is id so it does not make sense that you take .id of id ;)

Comment: true, it's not a good name, I have a lot of similare variables, thats why : )